# Prove that Chern-Simons terms is invariant under infinitesimal gauge transformaions

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory

I am trying to prove that the Chern-Simons term is invariant under an infinitesimal transformation up to first order. I think I have almost solved it but I am completely and utterly stuck now.

I have that the potential transforms as: $A_{\mu}\rightarrow A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\alpha+i[A_{\mu},\alpha]  $ and the Lagrangina is

$$\mathcal{L}=k\int d^3x\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}Tr\Big(A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\lambda}+\frac{2i}{3}A_{\mu}A_{\nu}A_{\lambda} \Big)= $$
where $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. Now I can rewrite the Lagrangian before I transform,

$$\mathcal{L}= k\int d^3x\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}Tr\Big(A_{\mu}(\partial_{\nu}+\frac{2i}{3}A_{\nu})A_{\lambda}\Big)$$

Then when I transform I get
$$\mathcal{L}=k\int d^3x\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}Tr\Big(\delta(A_{\mu})(\partial_{\nu}+2iA_{\nu})A_{\lambda}+A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\delta(A_{\lambda})\Big)  $$
where I have permuted the index with the help of Levi-cita and the trace so that I can transform the same factor of the potential and I can add them so I lose the factor of 1/3.

Before the I insert the actual transformation I know that the commutator $[A_{\mu},\epsilon]$ is zero as I can use the cyclic properties of the trace. And I can use partial integration to move some derivatives so that I have two on the same term and they cancel. As it is symmetric and multiplied with the Levi-Cevita symbols which is anti-symmetric is zero.

After I still get 
$$\mathcal{L}=k\int d^3x\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}Tr\Big(2A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\lambda}+2iA_{\mu}A_{\nu}A_{\lambda}+2i\partial_{\mu}\alpha A_{\nu}A_{\lambda}\Big) $$
I don't know how to simplify it further.

EDIT:
I figured out my mistake. If I only took the variation terms, i.e $\partial_{\mu}\alpha$ and inserted the indices, then used the cyclic property of the trace. All terms vanished.

Comment: I have changed $\epsilon$ to $\alpha$.